# How to make input values present after submitting a form

Tags: python, django, forms

Using checkbox widgets, I perform some filtering on data. Whenever I tick a checkbox, after submitting the form (applying a filter), the checkbox in unticked again. I'd like to prevent this. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you have a simple reproducible case for this that we can use?

Comment: I have `views.py` but I'm not even sure its a view issue, is it?

Comment: How are you creating the checkboxes? If you're using Django forms, you need to provide the initial state as either an `initial` argument for the appropriate field or as part of making the form bound - the latter is probably what you want for successive filterings and redisplays.

Comment: Im using Django forms, yes. Can you please drop me a link to django docs on this latter solution you mention?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms

Comment: You may reinstatiate the form with the POST data in your view. You may also save the underlying model of your form or the coresponding data (if you got no model underlying) to the database and redirect to a page where the saved data is shown or used to instantiate a form.